# Configure a network with an AirPort Extreme and Mac Mini Server?

Tags: time-capsule, file-sharing, airport, server.app

I'm trying to set up a Mac Mini Server for Local File Sharing, Calendar, and Contacts, but I also want to be able to access everything remotely through a domain. I'm using an AirPort Extreme as my router, I also have a Time Capsule configured to back up the entire Mac Mini Server.

That said, I also want to have multiple configured users so that I can harness permissions so that all files aren't available to every user. Also I want to have 2 Administrators for the network.

I've been messing with the settings and thought I had it working, but there seems to be an issue now with permissions. Only admins can login and everyone else can't even connect to the server.

If it even matters, I also have a separate remote dedicated linux server and a domain already.

I'm tempted to start from scratch, but if I do, where do I start? Is "File Sharing" the correct approach? or should I use something else?

Comment: What I'm aiming for is more along the lines of turning the Mac Mini into a file server that is accessible from anywhere. The only reason I even mentioned the Time Capsule is because it's part of the network which is backing up the server. The Time Capsule also goes offsite at the end of every day.

Answer (score 1):

Just buy [the Server app](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/). It costs about $20 which is a real bargain. There's also a wonderful video tutorial on the server setup [on YouTube by Todd Olthoff](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoaPplhfi5Nx8DMt6N9yIQknVrto_U7rL). I installed a server with about the same configuration as the one you are contemplating and it took me a while to complete.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I already have OS X Server, was just trying to get everything configured.